# What can be termed treason on the part of a bank special assistant in India?

Tags: meaning

Say a special assistant of a bank in India — before and after office hours — takes part in a question and answer site of Stack Overflow, many other sites in the Stack Exchange network and Quora. Can his participation be called *treason,* if his participation goes against India and his co-workers and colleagues, or against all banks in India?

Comment: This is a site about the English  language, not behavior. You should probably ask here https://workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is he compromising the national security?

Comment: @USER  66974-At the very outset I have made my objective clear and succinct. user-37920

Comment: This is off-topic here. Sorry

Comment: If you're asking what treason is, then a dictionary will tell you: it's seditious activity against the state. If you're asking whether looking at Stack Exchange is treasonable, we can't offer any opinion as we're not lawyers (nor does [law.se] Stack Exchange offer advice).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's either off-topic (regarding law) or answerable by common references.